# Give oracle query for this

Tags: database, oracle

one table have  4 columns

> (jobid ,start_time,end_time,date)

like

```
job_id start_time     end_time       date
p1     12.12.12am     12.14.14am    1-12-13
p2     12.17.12am     12.17.25 am   1-21-13
p1     10.13.15pm     10.18.15pm    2-12-13
p2     10.10.15pm     10.11.15pm    2-12-13
```

I want to find date when job_id p2 occurs before job_id p1 .

I already tried below query but it is not giving right o/p.

```
select date from table1 t inner join table1 t1 where t.jobId='p1' 
and t1.job_id='p2' and 
t.endtime> t1.endtime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select t.date from table1 t 
inner join table1 t1 on t.date = t1.date
where t.job_id = 'p1' 
    and t1.job_id = 'p2' 
    and t.end_time > t1.end_time;
```

You were missing the on for your join. that would give you a all the combinations for both tables. This way, you only compare records from the same date.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e39f/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( job_id, start_time, end_time, "date" ) AS
          SELECT 'p1', TO_DATE( '12.12.12am', 'HH.MI.SSAM' ), TO_DATE ( '12.14.14am', 'HH.MI.SSAM' ), TO_DATE ( '1-12-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', TO_DATE( '12.17.12am', 'HH.MI.SSAM' ), TO_DATE ( '12.17.25am', 'HH.MI.SSAM' ), TO_DATE ( '1-12-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p1', TO_DATE( '10.13.15pm', 'HH.MI.SSAM' ), TO_DATE ( '10.18.15pm', 'HH.MI.SSAM' ), TO_DATE ( '2-12-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', TO_DATE( '10.10.15pm', 'HH.MI.SSAM' ), TO_DATE ( '10.11.15pm', 'HH.MI.SSAM' ), TO_DATE ( '2-12-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( t."date", 'DD-MM-YY' ) AS "date",
       TO_CHAR( t.start_time, 'HH.MI.SSAM' ) AS start_time,
       TO_CHAR( t.end_time,   'HH.MI.SSAM' ) AS end_time
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  job_id = 'p1'
AND    EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM   tbl x
                WHERE  x.job_id = 'p2'
                AND    x."date" = t."date"
                AND    x.end_time < t.start_time )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e39f/6/0)**:

```
|     DATE | START_TIME |   END_TIME |
|----------|------------|------------|
| 02-12-13 | 10.13.15PM | 10.18.15PM |
```